# Use same state as child state for all other states in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible for me to define a state in UI router that acts as a child state for all other states or for a list of parent states?

I have a `login` state that opens a modal that then is used for logging in or signing up etc.

Currently, I've defined it as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state('index',{
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html',
    controller: 'indexCtrl'
}).state('index.login',{
    url:'login',
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
        $modal.open({
            windowClass: 'modal fade login-modal',
            templateUrl: "/static/partials/modals/loginModal.html",
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        }).result.finally(function() {
            $state.go('^');
        });
    }]
});
```

What I'd like to do is have

```
$stateProvider.state('index',{
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html',
    controller: 'indexCtrl'
}).state('login',{
    url:'login',
    parent: 'List of parent states here', //States that can be defined as parents
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
        $modal.open({
            windowClass: 'modal fade login-modal',
            templateUrl: "/static/partials/modals/loginModal.html",
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        }).result.finally(function() {
            $state.go('^');
        });
    }]
});
```

If not, how can I use `ui-router` to achieve what I have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the question right, but it looks to me like you want a single parent state (login) and multiple children states (login, signup, ...).

If this is the case, you can create you main state as `abstract` and then create the children..

```
$stateProvider
  .state("loginDialog", {
    url: "/login/",
    templateUrl: "loginDialog.html",
    abstract: true
  })
  .state("loginDialog.login", {
    url: "", //default partial shown in loginDialog
    templateUrl: "login.html"
  })
  .state("loginDialog.signup", { //another view shown instead of login
    url: "^/login/signup/",
    templateUrl: "signup.html"
  });
```